# Memory corruption during string tokenizing

Tags: c++, c++11, strtok, crash-dumps, memory-corruption

I am facing memory corruption and crash when doing a string tokenize. The crash is not occuring in the first time of processing . It takes more than an hour to crash. The problemmatic

```
    wchar_t *query = new wchar_t[inQry.length() + 1];

    memset(query, NULL, inQry.length() + 1);
    memcpy(query, inQry.c_str(), inQry.size());


    wchar_t *Tok = wcstok(query, L" ");

    headStr = L"";
    tableName = L"QUERY";

    while(Tok != NULL)
    {
        vectorSQLEntry.push_back(Tok);
        Tok = wcstok(NULL, L" ");
    }

    int tokCount = vectorSQLEntry.size();
    if(query != NULL)
    {
    delete query;
    }
```

When diagonized with debugdiag and analyzing the dump created, it pointed out some other line in the code.(sometimes the line will be `delete query`).
So i removed the `query` as pointer and declared as wstring. And i removed the 
initialization of `headStr` and `tableName` inbetween wcstok and while loop(code as below).

```
wstring  tmpQuery = inQry;
wchar_t *Tok = wcstok((wchar_t*)tmpQuery.c_str(), L" ");
while(Tok != NULL)
{
    vectorSQLEntry.push_back(Tok);
    Tok = wcstok(NULL, L" ");
}
```

With this code the crash is not occurring.! So what is the problem with the initial code? This crash dragged me more than two days.

Comment: What does `vectorSQLEntry` hold? What's the exact type?

Comment: vector's definition -- vector<wstring> vectorSQLEntry;

Comment: When you have problems with memory corruption, you should also demonstrate that Valgrind couldn't identify problems - otherwise it looks as if you just haven't tried.

Answer (score 2):

Your delete statement should be `delete []query;`  I would expect you to be running out of memory after a while and that probably causing new to fail and a crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(query != NULL)
```

Query can not be null because `new` will throw an exception if fails.

```
 wcstok((wchar_t*)tmpQuery.c_str(), L" ");
```

You are trying to write into read-only memory corrupting string.

Comment: "You are trying to write into read-only memory corrupting string." - But with this code i dint get any crash..! Do u mean , if i access the tmpQuery after this line i ll get an exception?

Comment: @Sel_va Technically nothing prevents `wcstok` from crashing right away. Neither c-style and const-cast should appear in your code. And this piece definitely does not require any casts at all. Also you should update your question to include [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Depending on `vectorSQLEntry` type and whatever happens before / next you may have different problems.

Comment: vector's type is wstring. I just fill the vector with tokenized strings and search for a word and return that word(wstring) from this function.

Comment: @VTT new does not always throw an exception, it depends on the implementation, and if new has been overridden.  If its creation of a third party type, I would always check for ptr==null after a new.

Comment: @CodeGorilla Both default and custom allocation functions that are not marked as non-throwing are required to throw an exception that matches `std::bad_alloc` if allocation fails. Using custom allocation function that does not follow this requirement and / or checking return value of operator new that is not marked as non-throwing is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem and I found the right way to solve it.
You didn't initialize the variable `query` correct. Your code is :

```
memset(query, NULL, inQry.length() + 1);
```

The third parameter is not right. You should modify it just like follow code:

```
memset(query, NULL, (inQry.length() + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));
...
delete[] query;
```

Then it will work normally.